# Getting state from history.push

Tags: reactjs

How do I access state from history.push() in the redirected route.

For example,

```
history.push({ pathname: '/order', state: {orderId} })
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to navigate you can pass the props in the following format

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/order',
  state: {orderId: response.data }
})
```